# Blazor QuickGrid - Add class based on row item context property value

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0, quickgrid

I need to add class to a row cell based on its value.

Something like:

```
@inject DataSource Data

<div class="grid">
    <QuickGrid Items="@Data.People">
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(c => c.PersonId)" Sortable="true"  />
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(c => c.FirstName)" Sortable="true" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="@(c => c.LastName)" Sortable="true" />

        <PropertyColumn Property="@(c => c.BirthDate)" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" Sortable="true" Class="@GetClass(context.BirthDate)" />
    </QuickGrid>
</div>

@code {
    string GetClass(DateOnly birthDate) => birthDate.Year < 2000 ? "table-success" : "table-warning"; 
}
```

I am unable to access the item property from within other parameters of PropertyColumn.

I tried to use TemplateColumn, but it only works for the tag within the cell and not the entire cell itself.

```
<TemplateColumn>
    <div class="@GetClass(context.BirthDate)">
        @context.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    </div>
</TemplateColumn>
```

This also means that I have to manually handle sorting for the column which was automatically available through PropertyColumn tag.